# Magento ->addAttributeToFilter - removing selected product from collection

Tags: magento

I'm looking to make a simple related products block on my product page, we have a vast amount of products so at the moment it's not really feasible to use the backend entry of upsells etc.

Below i've some code which selects similar products via the use of 'prod_colour' - so if a person is viewing a product of beige colour, it returns all beige coloured products in the category, then chooses 4 by random to show.

```
<?php

$thiscolour = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getProd_colour(), 'prod_colour');
$bestsellers=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$collection=$bestsellers->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('prod_colour', $thiscolour);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$collection->getSelect()->limit(4);

?>
```

I'm just wondering how it's possible to remove the currently viewed product from the collection - for example if i'm viewing product 1, and products 1, 3, 5 , 7 are all the same colour, it returns all four products - i'd be looking to remove product 1 so the block will only show products 3, 5 and 7.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on product page so you get product id so you can use below filter condition on product collection

```
addAttributeToFilter('id', array('neq' => 'yourid'));
```

For further condition you can check [here](http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/addattributetofilter-conditionals-in-magento.html)

Comment: are you meaning to create a variable that grabs the product id - then use that variable where 'yourid' is? I've tried $prodid = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getId(), 'id'); and added the variable in place, but still no change!

Comment: you can directly put your id no need to define variable, you can also use sku condition instead of id

Comment: would it be possible to do it via a variable? just as all products need to remove themselves on their own product page - thanks for the link also - i've tried to put in the ID on its own also, but that still doesn't filter the product out!

Comment: I also printed the query out - it appears as

SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`prod_colour`, `e`.`small_image` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id='3' WHERE (e.prod_colour = '9') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4

Comment: You can also use variable that's not a problem

Comment: it looks like id condition is not there in your query

Comment: However it is included in the query - the query changes if i remove either of the other AddAttributeToFilter / Select lines, but it's as if it isn't recognising the AddAttributeToFilter ID line!

Comment: try out other condition like put sku instead of your id

Comment: strange - sku appears in the query! it outputs as AND (e.sku != 'test')

Comment: Ah - i've found a workaround - i'm using name instead of sku - a little bit more work but it doesn't seem to like using ID! Thanks for your help & getting me towards the solution!